# Angular 2 Http provider's observable subscribe not firing

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-observables

I'm having difficulty getting the `.subscribe()` method to fire on an observable in Angular 2. My setup is a provider that injects the `Http Service` with a method that returns the observable that a controller can interface with, and subscribe to.

I'm unclear why the subscribe doesn't fire when the method returns the observable and the controller chains a subscribe onto that. Any help is much appreciated.

**User Provider**

```
@Injectable()
export class UserResource {

    constructor( protected http: Http ) {}

    public getUsers(): Observable<User[]> {
        return this.http.get( '/api/users' )
            .map( (response: Response) => <User[]>response.json() )
            .catch( (error: Response | any) => {
                console.log( error );
                return Observable.throw( error );
            });
    }
}
```

**Users Controller**

```
export class UsersController {
    public usersEnrolled: User[]   = [];
    public usersUnenrolled: User[] = [];

    constructor( private userResource: UserResource ) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.userResource.getUsers()
            .subscribe(( users: User[] ) => {
                console.log( 'users', users ); // does not fire
                this.usersUnenrolled = users.filter( (user: User) => !user.isEnrolled );
                this.usersEnrolled   = users.filter( (user: User) => user.isEnrolled );
            },
            ( error ) => console.log( 'error', error ),
            () => console.log( 'completed' )
        );
    }
}
```

**Updated subscription to include callbacks for error and complete**

*Please note I excluded import statements for brevity of code.*

Comment: not sure if this might be the problem, but try to use the full url for the request like: `this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/users')` (or whatever the hostname is)

Comment: thx @lenny i kept that out for brevity, but it does have the host in my actual code. :)

Comment: or maybe there is something wrong with the type, what happens when use `any` instead of `User`?

Comment: Actually, a clearer way to debug this problem, is to set a debug breakpoint in your Sources pane, or add `debugger;` statement where you'd like to start and follow the execution path.

Comment: `.map( (response) => console.log(response.json()) )` what does that print out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a dork. The code works, it was a matter of a mismatch URL in the `http.get()` to our URL defined for a mock response from `MockBackend`. My apologies, everyone. Once I accounted for the mismatched URL, it worked as expected. Thanks for your help.

Not sure how to mark this as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 2):

You should add an error function to your subscription so you can see why.

```
.subscribe(
     users: User[] => console.log( 'users', users ),
     error => console.log('error',error),
     () => console.log('completed')
);
```

You are only passing in the 'next' function.  I find it helpful to use all three functions of subscribe()

Comment: Fair enough. I am doing that per your suggestion and nothing is being written to the console. I even added a console.log statement to `ngOnInit` as a sanity check to make sure the call to my `UserProvider.getUsers().subscribe()` is being called; it is.

Answer (score 0):

You are subscribing to users: User[], but you're mapping to json. If you do:

```
.subscribe(users => {
console.log(users);
}
```

Do you get anything written to the console?

Comment: Nothing is written to the console. I updated the callbacks (above and in my actual code) as suggested by `Jeff Justice` above. Also, I updated to what you're suggesting, but didn't fix it. :(

Answer (score 0):

Possibly relevant, I have never seen the constructor pattern you have included in a Service; that is, calling `super()`. Angular handles this for  you by simply including it in the constructor as a parameter. You then leave the `constructor` body empty.

Usually, I would instantiate my service class like this:

```
import { Http, Response } from "@angular/http";

export class UserResource {

  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  getUsers(): Observable<User[]> {
    //
  }
}
```

But I will reiterate my comment: [use source breakpoints if using Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/breakpoints) or `debugger;` statements, it will make what's happening *much* clearer. If you have source maps, you can put the break-point in the TypeScript source.

Comment: My bad. My `UserResource` is extending a custom `ApiResource` class. I'll go ahead and remove that from my example code as it's likely not relevant.

Comment: @TomDoe The fact that the super method is called on `http` and it's http that's not working may be highly relevant. Don't just remove it from the question if it's not what your source actually does. :)

Comment: Ha! I removed it from my code as well to pinpoint why this isn't working. Removing it had no effect. :(

Comment: I appreciate it :)